# Is it possible to port a Windows RT app to a Windows Phone app?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, async-await, winrt-async

Just recently released an application to the Windows Store, and I'm wondering if it is possible to "downgrade" it to Windows Phone 7.1 - until Windows Phone 8 will arrive.

The real problem is with the async stuff, I've found the "Async Targeting Pack", but it requires Visual Studio 2012; however VS2012 doesn't work with the Phone SDK 7.0, 7.1.

I'm not in the mood to install old and ugly Visual Studio 2010 on my brand new Windows 8 machine :)

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Unless you have desperate requirement (your client has 1000 WP7 devices in the field), I wouldn't bother. WP8 will be out any minute and WP7 will ancient history very soon.

Comment: @Craig, I expect taht WP7.5 (or 7.8) will be about for a long time, as low end phones are being released now with it rather then WP8

Comment: You are probably right. It depends on the target market you are looking at then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 has arrived and, unfortunately, it does not allow you to compile applications for Windows Phone 7.1 if the code uses async/await. You can try to port the code to Windows Phone 8 which does support async/await out of the box.

If you still want to have a WP7.1 port of your application and still use the async/await feature, you have no option other than installing VS2010 express for WP7 + async ctp 3.

Although [Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576) has arrived, you cannot target WP7 projects since WP7 is Silverlight 4, and targeting pack is for Silverlight 5.

UPDATE: There is a way to compile WP7 applications on Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone by using this nifty [NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async). However, note that it is currently in prerelease version.

Comment: exactly, that's a pity MS didn't made the two compatible. The old 7.x  has some ~2% market share, it will take a year or more I guess for 8 to get to this level, so you decide: go for an estabilished market or don't do anything just wait.

Answer (score 0):

Well Windows Phone 8 suppose to launch tomorrow so why do you need to Downgrade your application to Windows Phone 7.1?

[This](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/09/12/windows-phone-8-sdk-preview-program-is-now-open.aspx) article might hold's answer to your problem.

> Today you may have also seen the online launch event for Visual Studio 2012. The Windows Phone SDK 8.0 is built on top of Visual Studio 2012, and will give you the ability to build applications and games that target both Windows Phone 8 as well as Windows Phone 7.5. Windows Phone SDK 7.1 can be installed side-by-side with Visual Studio 2012 and runs on Windows 8.